# Which line extraction algorithms are used in gmapping and cartographer packages?

Tags: slam, navigation, cartographer, ros-kinetic, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was wondering which line extraction algorithms are used in gmapping and cartographer packages?

I couldn't find this information on the ROS wiki websites.

Some of the possible options are

- Split-and-merge
- Hough-transform
- RANSAC
- Incremental
- Line-regression
- Expectation maximization

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298804/which-line-extraction-algorithms-are-used-in-gmapping-and-cartographer-packages?/) by [csg](https://answers.ros.org/users/36089/csg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2018-07-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

These are 2D planar slam algorithms, not line detectors. I'd recommend just reading the code. Gmapping is very short and Cartographer has more than adequate documentation to guide you in what each are doing, but there is not a line detection component in any of these I do not believe.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2018-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1